# How to get the number of unanswered questions by tag from stackoverflow api?

Tags: stackexchange-api, stackexchange

There is a call that return the number of total questions by tag https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/tags/java/info?order=desc&sort=popular&site=stackoverflow

But how would you get the number of unanswered questions by tag?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming. It is *just* about the SE API.  This question is only **[on topic at Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/help/on-topic)**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For unanswered questions, use [the `/questions/unanswered` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unanswered-questions):

[api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/unanswered?tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=total](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/unanswered?tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=total)

For questions with ***no*** answers, use [the `/questions/no-answers` route](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/no-answer-questions):

[api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/no-answers?tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=total](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/no-answers?tagged=java&site=stackoverflow&filter=total)

Comment: ahhh just missed the `tagged` param when looked through the docs, I wish there was an example containing the `tagged` param in the docs.